# identifying image object using css for protractor automation

Tags: css, angularjs, css-selectors, protractor

I am using protractor for angular js automation. I am trying to get the 'fa fa-something' text from the below  element structure using css identifier-

```
<div class="Itemlistcontainer">
      <ul class="itemlist sortlist ui-sortable">
      <!-- ngRepeat: Item in Items | orderBy:CustomSort:false --><li ng-repeat=" Item in Items | orderBy:CustomSort:false" ng-show="!searchinput || ([Item.Name]|filter:searchinput).length" ng-class="{ 'itemdisabled' : !CanUseTask(Item) || deactivate }" class="ng-scope ui-draggable">
        <div bo-attr="" bo-attr-id="Item.Id" bo-attr-title="Item.Details | html2string" class="label itemlabel" id="3d991564-a1a9-49ab-8659-a26e00fbfae6" title="Blah blah blah.">
          <span>
            <i ng-class="itemIconClass(Item)" style="margin-right: 5px;" class="fa fa-something"></i>
          </span><span bo-text="item.Name | ellipse : 32">Item Name</span>
        </div>
      <!--ngRepeat: Item in Items....and the list goes on
```

I need to know under what Item in Items was this 'fa fa-something' found. I am using `element(By.css('ul.itemlist i.itemIconClass(Item)').getAttribute('class').getText()`
which is not working.

Comment: `getAttribute('class').getText()` will never work, you're doing nothing with the `class` attribute there, `getText()` works because `ElementFinder` is chainable that's all.

Answer (score 2):

```
element(By.css('ul.itemlist i.itemIconClass(Item)').getAttribute('class').getText()
```

can't work as you're  trying to interpolate an angular template expression in a protractor element selector

I think you need :

```
element(By.css('ul.itemlist i.fa.fa-something').getAttribute('class').getText()
```

And to determine `what Item in Items was this 'fa fa-something' found` maybe you need an ID (which will be easier to read, no need to parse class attribute by extracting `fa fasomething` etc...

Comment: will not work for me as for finding 'fa fa-something' I will need to use 'fa.fa-something' in the css identifier as per your solution.

Comment: your question in not clear, add some more unit test code